# Synonym of "also"

Tags: grammar

I have a question about the word "also". I know similar words like "furthermore" or "besides", but my friend told me that "also" is used in a complete idea or sentence. I'm very confused and I can't find specific information about my problem on Internet. I don't want to repeat "also" all the time in a interview.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *TOO*. The most common, pedestrian word which serves the same function (although the placement is a little different).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't listen to your friend too much, "furthermore" is a classic substitute for 'also' and I as a native British English speaker use it all the time in formal and informal contexts to replace the word 'also'.

You can also use 'in addition to', 'as well as', 'likewise', 'moreover' to achieve the desired effect.

This is a problem that is quite common to be honest and you will have to repeat the word also at some point so don't worry too much.

You can also use words like 'secondly' and 'finally' to replace 'also', but obviously only in certain contexts.

Note though that you could have a sentence such as 'I went to the shop and also went to the park", in this and similar cases the direct substitution for 'also' doesn't work (maybe this is what your friend was talking about).

Comment: Would you care to illustrate the use of *Besides* to indicate contradictory following information? As an adverb I would have thought it more common to mean *in addition to*, *as well as*!

Comment: Actually now that I think about it you are right it's not contradictory information but just additional, I will edit the answer. However I fell that besides is more likely to replace 'anyway' than 'also' and has a slight nuance in meaning, but maybe that's more of a colloquial thing.